# How to remove, using script, non present entry inside legend symbology?

Tags: qgis

Using Qgis after loading shp file i loaded a general qml files that are coded for a specific field for my shp.  Inside qml are coded a larger number of symbology of the field that not all are present inside my shp. I will from pyhton console delete all entry in legend (loaded from qml) that have zero count geometry inside the shp, suppose Shp to purge is the current.